# binary search tree pointer problem

Tags: c

I tried to implement a binary search tree for the purpose of (re-)learning C. The problem is that the this `current = new;` does not work as desired because the tree.root is still a null pointer after adding two nodes. What's wrong with that?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct BinaryNode {
    int key;
    double value;
    struct BinaryNode *left;
    struct BinaryNode *right;
    } BinaryNode;

typedef struct BinaryTree {
    struct BinaryNode *root;
    } BinaryTree;


static void binary_tree_insert_recursive(BinaryNode *current, BinaryNode *new) {
    if (current == NULL || current->key == new->key) {
        current = new;
    } else if (current->key > new->key) {
        binary_tree_insert_recursive(current->left, new);
    } else if (current->key < new->key) {
        binary_tree_insert_recursive(current->right, new);
    }
}

void binary_tree_insert(BinaryTree *tree, int key, double value) {
    BinaryNode *new = (BinaryNode *) malloc(sizeof(BinaryNode));
    new->key = key;
    new->value = value;
    binary_tree_insert_recursive(tree->root, new);
}

int main(void) {
    BinaryTree tree;
    binary_tree_insert(&tree, 5, 123);
    binary_tree_insert(&tree, 10, 123);
    printf("%p\n", tree.root);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem with `current = new;`  is that you are changing your local copy of `current`. After the function is done, this modification is not visible.

I suspect you want something like:

```
static void binary_tree_insert_recursive(BinaryNode **current, BinaryNode **new)
{
    if (*current == NULL || (*current)->key == (*new)->key) {
    *current = *new;
    /* ... */
```

Well explained in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html).

Comment: @ahojnnes: You might need to consider also initializing the "left" and "right" pointers to NULL for every node you create. Also, don't name your variable "new", it's confusing.

Comment: @Andrei: is it not initialized with a null pointer by default?

Comment: @ahojnnes: They are not requited to be initialized to anything. Some compilers will initialize them to some "easy to see" values such as 0xcccccccc or 0xdeadbeef.

Answer (score 1):

`current` is a pointer to a node. When you pass it to `binary_tree_insert_recursive` from `binary_tree_insert` the *value* of the pointer is passed.  So although it is changed inside the called function, the change is not reflected in the calling function.  You need to modify the function to take the *address* of the pointer you wish to change:

```
 static void binary_tree_insert_recursive(BinaryNode **current, BinaryNode *new)
 {
         if (*current == NULL || (*current)->key == new->key)  {
             *current = new;
```

Answer (score 0):

`new` is a keyword. Choose a different variable name.

Comment: In C proper it's not. However, who knows what is the OP compiling it like. Didn't even specify the compiler, or the error message.

Comment: I thought this is C++? Nevertheless it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

all that `current = new` does is make it so that the variable `current` points at the thing that `new` is pointing at. No copying takes place, and the function has no effect on that codepath.