# Binary Search Tree not adding Element

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree for which I'm trying to implement an insert function. However when I test the code, I see that no element is getting added at all even though my logic seems fine to me. I feel like there is some C idiosyncrasy that I'm missing.

```
struct tree_element {
    int data;
    struct tree_element* left;
    struct tree_element* right;
};

typedef struct tree_element node;

void init(node* root){
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
    root->data = 0;
}

void insert(node* root, int val){
    if (root == NULL){
        root = (node*)(malloc(sizeof(node)));
        init(root);
        root->data = val;
        printf("added %i\n", val);
        return;
    }

    if (val > root->data){
        insert(root->right, val);
    }
    else {
        insert(root->left, val);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a double-pointer (a pointer to a pointer), but it's actually easier to return the node as the function result in `insert`.

Comment: Why would a double pointer be necessary? And what about the current code is preventing nodes from being added?

Comment: [One of *many* duplicates to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349196/binary-search-tree-pointer-problem).

Comment: When you do `insert(root->right, ...` you are passing a copy of the right pointer - the value that you (might) assign in `insert` never makes it back out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the `root` value within the function.
However, from the calling function perspective, nothing is changed.

This might work:

```
void insert(node** root, int val){
    if (*root == NULL){
        *root = (node*)(malloc(sizeof(node)));
        init(*root);
        (*root)->data = val;
        printf("added %i\n", val);
        return;
    }
    if (val > (*root)->data){
        insert(&((*root)->right), val);
    }
    else {
        insert(&((*root)->left), val);
    }
}
```

The fundamental concept is - when you pass in a pointer to a method, the method can change the data that the pointer is pointing to, but cannot alter the pointer itself.

Comment: While functionally identical, it might be easier/clearer to use a pointer reference instead of double pointer (i.e. `node* &root` instead of `node**`).

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis Not in C, at least, my friend.